# Не работает запрос на веб сервере

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте! Есть запрос:

```
select
  date_format(from_unixtime(datetime), '%Y-%m-%d') as datetime,
  sum(sum) as sum
from
  payments
WHERE
  `datetime` BETWEEN '1407872709' AND '1707872709'
group by
  date(from_unixtime(datetime))
```

Запрос нормально работает на локальном сервере и не работает веб сервере. Версии `php` и `mysql` везде одинаковы. 
myAdmin возвращает такой результат:

> SQL query: Documentation
>   select date_format( from_unixtime(datetime), '%Y-%m-%d') as datetime, 
>   sum(sum) as sum from payments WHERE `datetime` BETWEEN '1407872709' AND 
>   '1707872709' group by date(from_unixtime(datetime)) LIMIT 0, 25
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>   #1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'carilla.payments.datetime' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with 
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: `group by date(from_unixtime(datetime))` поменяйте на `group by datetime`

Comment: @Александр Белинский, спасибо! А почему `from_unixtime(datetime)` на веб сервере не работает можете подсказать?

Comment: Или напишите в group by вычисление даты точно так же как и в части select. Иначе MySQL не может понять, что по факту вы и группируете и выводите одинаковое время. Ну или как вариант, group by не менять а в части select делать `date_format( from_unixtime(MAX(datetime)), '%Y-%m-%d')`.

Comment: @Mike,  можете на моем запросе показать как это переделать, а то я в mysql совсем новичек(

Comment: @r.mcreal а для чего Вам выполнять заново эти функции? на момент `GROUP BY` у вас уже в `datetime` лежит вычисленное в `SELECT` значение. Не могу понять просто суть - зачем.

Comment: @Александр Белинский, сам запрос нашел в интернете, что там да как не разбираюсь, если честно( Задача запроса найти сумму всех заказов за некоторый промежуток по дням

Comment: @r.mcreal, тогда сделайте именно `group by datetime`. Оно будет брать не то, `datetime`, которое у Вас в таблице `payments`, а то, которое Вы вычислили. Вообще, порядок выполнения такой: сначала проверяются условия в WHERE и JOIN (я толком еще не понял каким образом оно там упорядочивается, для меня это всё еще магия), затем вычисляются поля из SELECT, потом делается GROUP BY по указанным полям, затем по полученным данным делается HAVING. Далее ORDER BY, и, наконец, LIMIT. Любой из этапов может быть опущен (кроме, быть может, SELECT-а)